# Marriage or no marriage

Tags: sex, husband-wife

I am a 28 years old man. I have an incredible desire to be emotionally and physically attached to someone of the opposite gender. However, I do not like the idea of providing for her and the children. I might be able to compromise on providing for her but I will never be in favor of having children. I have been looking all my life and here I am. Turning 29 but unable to find someone who would agree on my conditions. Yet, I still stand my ground and do not want anyone who disagrees with my conditions even if I have to live the rest of my life single. My question is, can I satisfy my desires through masturbation and am I commiting a sin by not marrying. Provided my circumstances.

Comment: This post includes two questions that are widely answered on the site: Is not marrying a sin: No. Is satisfying desires by masturbation in order not to commit a sin halal: Yes for some scholars others (the majority) consider masturbation haram. Your circumstances are not special: You won't die if you neither married nor stop masturbating.

Answer (score 1):

You're not badly being sinned for not wanting to be married, but it is preferred for you to be married in Islam

**For sex**

Islam says that sexual urge should be fulfilled only through marriage.